# Django File Upload ,can't add file field using form from instance object

Tags: python, django, forms, file-upload

I need to save a file upload object, but in two views... First views can save without problem, but the second i get nothing change in my object

I have a models.py

```
class file_upload(models.Model):

    x= models.FileField()
    y = models.FileField()
```

I have forms.py

```
class form_upload(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = file_upload
        fields = ('x',)    
        widgets={
            'x': FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

class form_upload_2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = file_upload
        fields = ('y',)
        widgets={
             'y': FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
```

I have created an objects, also have uploaded a file on "x", i need to add file on "y" using form_upload_2

this is my views.py

```
data_upl_instance = file_upload.objects.get(id=1)
form = form_upload2(request.FILES,request.POST,instance=data_upl_instance)

if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data['y'])
        form.save()

mydata['form'] = form

return render(request, "status.html", mydata)
```

this is my status.html

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
           <div class="alert alert-danger">
               {{ form }}
            </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn red">Upload</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

After i clicked submit, the result is

- Printed "None" on terminal
- Form is valid but nothing change, file
  cant be uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solve the problem, the problem is i have nothing in **request.POST**, i just need **request.FILES**.. so i change **"request.POST"** to **"request.POST or None"**

this is my new views.py

```
data_upl_instance = file_upload.objects.get(id=1)
form = form_upload2(instance=data_upl_instance)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = form_upload2(request.FILES,request.POST or None,instance=data_upl_instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data['y'])
        form.save()

mydata['form'] = form

return render(request, "status.html", mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `form_upload_2` class don't have field `y`. Change it to

```
class form_upload_2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = file_upload
        fields = ('y',)
        widgets={
         'y': FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
```

Also follow naming conventions while naming a class. `file_upload` is not a good class name. Use `FileUpload`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Also your form, please try to change like this

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = form_upload2(request.FILES,request.POST,instance=data_upl_instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data['y'])
        form.save()
else:
    form = form_upload2(instance=data_upl_instance)


mydata['form'] = form

return render(request, "status.html", mydata)
```

Comment: that's typo, im sorry

Comment: @ElijahPrune Is your file upload working fine now ? Can you accept the answer if all good ?

Comment: Can you check if your form is valid ? And try printing request.POST. See if POST dict is having the file path.

Comment: its only return middleware token

<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['FQ00pPXH5ErPAdjt1gZbmD3xvdvjlEblablablabla..........j']}>

Comment: please see the updated answer. you have to handle the condition of request.GET as well.

Comment: nothing changes, print form.cleaned_data['y'] still returning "None"

Comment: Are you submitting form using ajax ?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the file path is not sending to your view. May be there is something wrong with the html. do an inspect element in the browser and see if there is a file field and the field is inside the form tag.